# .Centering absolutely positioned div based on parent's width (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, centering

I am building a navigation bar that has a tiny arrow on the active tab (see attached picture)

DESIRED LOOK
[image: navigation bar]
CURRENT LOOK
[image: navbar 2]

The navigation bar is dynamically created based on my wordpress pages. The problem I am having is centering the little arrow on the active tab.

Currently, I am using jquery to place span tags after the current/active link.

```
$('li.current-menu-item a').after('<span></span>');
```

and my css is as follows:

```
#menu-nav{float:right; clear:right; margin-top:30px;font-family:'Arvo'}
#menu-nav li{margin: 0 10px; float:left;  }
#menu-nav a{color:#9c9c98;padding:6px 9px; font-size:17px; background:#e4e4e0; text-decoration:none;}
#menu-nav li.current-menu-item{position:relative;}
#menu-nav li.current-menu-item a{background: #41618c; color:#f4f4f3;}
#menu-nav span{ width:20px; height:11px; float:left;clear:left; background:url(images/active.png) no-repeat; position:absolute; top:27px; left:0; }
```

The problem I am having is again, getting the arrow to be centered on each tab. Currently, the span has a positoion of left:0. Typically, I would give it a value of 50% and set a negative margin-left of half the parent's width; however, the parent's widths keep changing (because each tab has different text. SO, I need a jquery solution that will center the arrow based on it's parents width. I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need positioning for this. Use `display:block` and `margin:auto` instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>Centering absolutely positioned div based on parent's width (Jquery)</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu-nav {list-style:none;}
        #menu-nav {float:right; clear:right; margin-top:30px;font-family:'Arvo'}
        #menu-nav li {list-style:none;margin: 0 10px; float:left;}
        #menu-nav a {color:#9c9c98;padding:6px 9px; font-size:17px; background:#e4e4e0; text-decoration:none;}
        #menu-nav li.current-menu-item a {background: #41618c; color:#f4f4f3;}
        #menu-nav li.current-menu-item span {display:block;width:20px; height:11px;margin:auto;background:url(images/active.png) no-repeat;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('li.current-menu-item a').after('<span></span>');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Artistse</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

---

For the record, I think you're taking the completely wrong approach and should ditch the JavaScript, instead changing the background image of the `<li>` element, using `padding-bottom` to make room for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>Centering absolutely positioned div based on parent's width (Jquery)</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu-nav {list-style:none;}
        #menu-nav {float:right; clear:right; margin-top:30px;font-family:'Arvo'}
        #menu-nav li {list-style:none;margin: 0 10px; float:left;}
        #menu-nav a {color:#9c9c98;padding:6px 9px; font-size:17px; background:#e4e4e0; text-decoration:none;}
        #menu-nav li.current-menu-item a {background: #41618c; color:#f4f4f3;}
        #menu-nav li.current-menu-item {background:url(images/active.png) no-repeat CENTER BOTTOM;padding-bottom:11px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Artistse</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yea completely slipped my mind, good call. Thanks! much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with LeguRi, try without Javascript, this is another approach with css, i like to put always a SPAN tag inside my link, you get one more level for use CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>Centering absolutely positioned div based on parent's width (Jquery)</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu-nav {
        margin:30px 0 0 0; padding:5px 0 0 0;
        float:right; clear:right; font-family:'Arvo'
        text-align:right;
        background:#ccc;
        }
            #menu-nav li {
            list-style:none;
            display:inline;
            }
                #menu-nav li a {
                display: inline-block;
                padding-bottom:11px;
                }
                    #menu-nav li a span {
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin: 5px 10px 0px 10px; padding:6px 9px;
                    font-size:17px; color:#9c9c98; text-decoration:none;
                    background:#e4e4e0;
                    }
                #menu-nav li.current-menu-item a  {
                background:url(images/active.png) center bottom no-repeat;
                }
                    #menu-nav li.current-menu-item a span {
                    background: #41618c; color:#f4f4f3;
                    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Artistse</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#"><span>News</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Store</a></span></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</a></span></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Personal advice: never use `<span>` without a `class` attribute or an `id` - [here is a lengthy explanation why](http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/not-blog/a-css-class) - so I'd change those to something like `<span class="hyperlink-text">`